# Which group is isomorphic to $\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Both matrices have determinant equal to -1, so their products are matrices with determinant $\in \{1,-1\}$. Can I conclude that this is isomorphic to $ O_2(\mathbb{R}) $ ?

Comment: This is a lttle fast for a conclusion. Note that the second matrix is not orthgonal, if you thought that they generate $O_2$ as a subgroup of the invertible matrices.

Comment: Expanding a little bit on Daniel Rust's answer. By looking at the determinant, if a product of finitely many $a$ and $b$ is equal to $1$, it must be of the form $(ab)^n=1$ or $(ba)^n=1$. So it suffices to check that $ab$ and $ba$ can't satisfy this. For instance, their spectra are not in the unit circle. So there is no trivial word in $a,b$.

Comment: @user10676 Like I said, consider the determinant to rule these out.

Comment: If $a(ba)^n=1$, then $(ba)^n=a\Rightarrow (ba)^{n-1}b=1\Rightarrow (ba)^{n-1}=b\Rightarrow a(ba)^{n-2}=1$. So, $(ba)^2=1$ which is not true in this case.

Comment: Here's a little error checking you can do: what is the cardinality of the group generated by those two matrices? What is the cardinality of $O_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a$ be the first matrix and $b$ be the second matrix.

Hint: you've probably already worked out that $a^2=1$ and $b^2=1$. So, any element in the group will be a word beginning and ending with an $a$ or $b$ and with alternating $a$s and $b$s in between. Start looking at these words and see if you can find an alternating word which looks like a matrix you already know. What does this tell you about the group?

Answer (score 6):

If you set $$a=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},~~b=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ exactly as @Daniel noted; you will find out that $$a^2=b^2=(ab)^3=1$$ The group with this relation has the form $$\langle a,b\mid a^2=1,b^2=1,(ab)^3=1\rangle$$ which is $D_6$ or $S_3$. The following codes written in GAP environment approved our result:

```
  gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b"); 
       a:=f.1;;
       b:=f.2;;
          s:=f/[a^2,b^2,(a*b)^3];;
      Size(s);
                                           6
      IsAbelian(s);
                                         false
      StructureDescription(s);
                                           S3
```

Comment: Thanks, Babak! Just to add that one could investigate properties of `Group([[0,1],[1,0]],[[1,-1],[0,-1]])` as well.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Believe me, I spent times to find a way to construct such this group just be using matrices a and b above, but couldnot. Thanks bro. :-)

Comment: Helpful work! Gap to the rescue, again! +

Answer (score 6):

Every finitely generated group is at most countable infinite. On the other hand,the group $O_2(\mathbb R)$ is easily seen to be uncountable.

Therefore your group is not isomorphic to $O_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: I always admire your neat hints, Mariano. :-)